# Drone Imagery Footprints & Quaternions

Tags: imagery, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, photogrammetry, footprint

I'm trying to use Drone Imagery Metadata to plot precise (or nearly precise) Imagery footprints on the the ground and I need some help with Photogrammetry / Trigonometry / Quaternions

My repo is located [here](https://github.com/spifftek70/Drone-Footprints/blob/master/drone_fp/drone_fp.py).
I'm trying to port the calculations from [this repo](https://github.com/rijesha/CamFootprintTester/blob/master/CamFootprintTester/MainWindow.xaml.cs) written in C#

I have code that can do it as long as the Camera is exactly NADIR, but it's not as accurate as I really need.  I should take into account the Gimbal `pitch`, `roll`, & `yaw`.  With DJI drones, this data is **NOT** relative to the aircraft, but entirely stand-aline (or so I'm told).

My math is close but I'm a bit off somewhere.  In the image below, the smaller polygons are made using NADIR hard coded and using the estimated GSD using the image size and focal length.

The larger polygon set is trying to utilize the pitch, roll, and yaw... but it's not right.  The dots are the camera's counterpoint at the trigger of the shutter.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  Needed to port in his exact quaternion processes.